file system on an emmc damaged by a power surge?
I'm running a Quartz64 (Model A) booting off an eMMC drive,
and it recently suffered a file system corruption
after a power outage due to a lightening strike. 
After this, it wouldn't boot up.  I had a backup eMMC drive,
so I was able to return the Quartz64 to working order,
but I'm still trying to deduce what happened. 
Here are the steps I followed:

I ran badblocks on the eMMC, and it returned no issues. 
That seemed weird,
since I'd guessed that the power surge had just fried the eMMC.

I ran fsck on the drive's partitions' file systems,
and it detected errors, but was able to fix them. 
After this, the Quartz64 booted off the damaged eMMC without issue.


So, it looks like whatever happened just corrupted the file systems, but not the device itself. But, here's what I'm left wondering:

Are there any other checks I can/should do on the eMMC to check for damage?

If the damage to the file system was just due to an abrupt power-off,
is there anything I could do to configure the system to be less vulnerable?

This is more of a hardware question, but what are best practices with grounding single-board computers? My understanding was that grounding through the attachment bolts was enough, but perhaps not so.


This system is running Gentoo Linux.

I’m voting to close this question because this question appears to only tangentially be related to Linux/Unix, and almost entirely related to hardware.

Sounds like your eMMC is ok, or at least no less reliable than that kind of device ever is. Regular backups are recommended and a spare device is a sensible precaution. The most practical solution to avoid this kind of issue is to add an Uninterruptible Power Supply with surge protection.

Chris, I partly agree, this question certainly stemmed from a hardware issue. But I'd love some linux/inux insight into question #2, how to configure a system to be more robust against abrupt power offs.
I'm looking at the setup now, and it seems that it's using ext2  for the root FS. Probably, I should switch to ext4, but are there other measures I could take?
PonJar, agreed, a UPS is definitely needed!
